# Same radiobutton, same position. Why they are misaligned?

Tags: html, css

I have a ordered list that have some sentences and some radiobuttons.

I have the expected result, but I see a weird thing: the radio buttons are misaligned. I try to replicate the issue and [make a simple html with only the relevant code](http://jsfiddle.net/9TEdJ/2/).

That's a zoomed picture of the result I have (I put the turquoise lines in PS to see better the effect):

[image]

And that's the expected result:
[image]

As you can see in the first zoomed picture, the radio buttons are misaligned. Why this behaviour? How can I fix this?

**The code I have tried:**

```
<div class="test">
<ol class="test_inner">
        <li>
            <div>chanante ipsum dolor sit amet, quis eveniet mangurrián</div>                                 
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio2"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio2"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio2" checked="checked"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>zanguango magna ex labore bufonesco gambitero</div>           
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio3"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio3" checked="checked"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio3"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>chotera nisi chavalada pepinoninoni ullamco nisi ullamco</div>                                   
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio4" checked="checked"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio4"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio4"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>aliqua tontiploster sed eveniet sed ex viejuno</div>                                           
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio5"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio5" checked="checked"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio5"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>cosica soooy crossoverr to sueltecico ad ex gaticos ullamco</div>                                
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio6"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio6"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio6" checked="checked"/>
            </div>
        </li>
                <li>
            <div></div>                                 
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio7"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio7"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio7" checked="checked"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>ea elit aliqua minim bizcoché pepinoninoni</div>           
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio8"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio8" checked="checked"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio8"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>nisi minim ayy qué gustico enim ullamco saepe minim labore, nisi fresquete, super ñoño eveniet cartoniano magna</div>                                   
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio9" checked="checked"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio9"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio9"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>adipisicing quis eres un pirámidee veniam</div>                                           
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio0"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio0" checked="checked"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio0"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>síberet traeros tol jamón</div>                                
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio1"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio1"/>
                <input type="radio" name="myRadio1" checked="checked"/>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**The css I have:**

```
.test ol.test_inner {list-style:none; counter-reset:list; font-size:90%;}
.test ol.test_inner li {padding:.3em 0 .3em .5em; background:gray;}
.test ol.test_inner:before {content:"1 2 3"; text-align:right; display:block; font-size:110%; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:0.6em;}
.test ol.test_inner li:nth-of-type(odd) {background:pink;}
.test ol.test_inner li:before {counter-increment:list; content:counter(list, lower-alpha) ") "; color:#cbaa0e; padding-right:.5em; font-weight:bold;}
.test ol.test_inner li div {position:relative; display:inline-block; width:15%; text-align:right; vertical-align:middle}
.test ol.test_inner li div:first-child {width:80%; text-align:left;}
.test ol.test_inner li div input[type="radio"] {opacity:1; height:1.6em; width:1.6em; cursor:pointer; margin:0;}
```

For more details, I see the bad aligment in all browsers.

**EDIT:** As *Goombah* and *codingstill* alerts me, the horizontal misaligment is caused by the letters in the alpha list (different widths). But I still have the doubt why some radios are vertically misaligned too. Finally, I think this need another question. I'll leave the whole question here only for inquiry purposes if any user finds the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you try position: absolute?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Mmmmhhh... i prefer to avoid it. I want the website to be responsive and flexible, and that solution makes me do a lot of mediaqueries to avoid the overlap between the sentence and the radios (in small widths). Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: I just saw your edit. The vertical misalignment is consistent in all browsers? Have you tried to use a reset css http://www.cssreset.com/ or normalize.css http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: Yes, I use normalize. But I'm not sure about this last issue because in my work (win7 - 1280x1024) I see the misalignment but in my home (win8 - 1400x900) I don't (both with same browser version of FF and CH). Also, in win7 I see the radio buttons BIG and sharp, however in win8 I see them in normal size but with an invisible padding, also antialiased (?). I'm start considering to ask for all in another question...

Comment: It seems it could be a rendering issue (browser issue) and not a css/html issue, so a new question might be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue occurs because of the css rule below and because the font used is not monospaced and thus `i)` takes less space than `h)`.

```
.test ol.test_inner li:before {
    content: counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

To fix this you can set the `<li>` as inline-block and apply a specific width.

```
.test ol.test_inner li:before {
    color: #CBAA0E;
    content: counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
    counter-increment: list;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5JJr/1/) with the fix.

Comment: ....or I can use a monospaced font, I see. Thank you very much, I totally forgot the list items, as they does not are there. But I still have the vertical align problem. Some radio buttons are 1px down than its "brothers" (in the same line).

Comment: Yes, you could use a monospaced font. I didn't suggest it though, because you it would limit you to a small set of fonts to choose from!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the letters in your first row are of variable width (the ones in your :before).

Try this:

CSS

```
.test ol.test_inner li:before {
    counter-increment:list; 
    content:counter(list, lower-alpha) ") "; 
    color:#cbaa0e; 
    padding-right:.5em; 
    font-weight:bold; display: 
    inline-block; 
    width: 15px;
}
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TEdJ/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Take a look at your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TEdJ/4/). Is this better?

Comment: It looks just fine in my Fiddle. Maybe there is something going on in his code elsewhere that affects the alignment.

Comment: I know I've experienced similar issues across various IE browsers. can't remember if I fixed it or sat in missery. I feel ur pain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you adding lower-alpha by:before, why not just style the li's instead of using before?

Comment: Because the different color or the letters in the list ;)